# Facebook Checkins attach photos

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I am testing http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/. Looks like this SDK does not have Facebook Checkin features developed. Can anyone who used this SDK confirm? If its included in SDK can someone shed light on it. I searched their source code for "Places", "Publish_Checkins", "Checkin", "Check" and did not find anything relevant to Facebook checkin.

Update:
I found out a way but I am not sure if its correct. In extended_permissions I am using Publish_Checkins. I created dynamic parameters with placeid, message, coordinates, user tags and did PostAsync(parameters). When I logged in to facebook with the application, I was asked to grant checkin permissions to my app. The checkin was posted on my wall and even on the place page where I checkedin.

Comment: If you have figured out your problem then please add it as an answer.